Как на Android 13+ прописать фиксированный путь при выборе файлов
Пишу программу для Android (используя Kotlin), которая открывает бинарные файлы и редактирует их. Насколько мне известно, на последних версиях Андройда нельзя прописать фиксированный путь к файлу, а необходимо выбирать файлы вручную через файловый менеджер.
Так, на данный момент моя программа работает таким образом: заходишь в программу, жмешь на кнопку "Выбрать бинарный файл номер 1", открывается файловый менеджер, ищешь этот файл и выбираешь его. Затем в программе появляется новая кнопка "Выбрать бинарный файл номер 2"... и так далее. Для работы необходимо выбрать 5 бинарных файлов, после чего отрывается окно для редактирования.
Есть идеи, возможно ли как то упростить процесс, чтобы не выбирать файлы вручную?

Добавить в ассеты?

А что вы имели в виду под фиксированным путём? Вы можете запросить выбор папки и в этой папке читать, создавать, редактировать любые файлы без дополнительных запросов.

Хотел сделать так: в меню программы будет одна кнопка, при нажатии на которую будут загружаться 5 файлов (по очереди), без необходимости выбирать каждый файл отдельно.

Ну так а откуда должны взяться эти файлы и как ваша программа должна понять что загружать нужно именно эти, а не другие? Должны ли эти файлы быть доступны другим приложениям, или только вашему? Как-то подробнее излагайте свои хотелки, чтобы и нам было понятно.
